# List view html/js interface

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this list view component and am pretty
happy with how it came out.

Im looking for critique on what I could improve regarding
code readability, best practices and perhaps performance, it
seems pretty fast to me, granted the picsum url takes a bit time to load,
in production I´d likely have just a file url there.

[Heres the codepen link](https://codepen.io/Epsilon6/pen/YzLzaNN)

Heres my code laid out:

```js
// JS 
var projects = [
  {
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/500?grayscale',
    title: 'Converse',
    category: 'design',
    date: '22.03.19',
    descriptionItems: 
    [
      { 
        title: 'BRIEF',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      },
      { 
        title: 'CONFLICTS',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/500?grayscale',
    title: 'IBM',
    category: 'development',
    date: '10.03.16',
    descriptionItems: 
    [
      { 
        title: 'BRIEF',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      },
      { 
        title: 'CONFLICTS',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/500?grayscale',
    title: 'RedBull',
    category: 'design',
    date: '05.11.22',
    descriptionItems: 
    [
      { 
        title: 'BRIEF',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      },
      { 
        title: 'CONFLICTS',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/500?grayscale', 
    title: 'Microsoft',
    category: 'development',
    date: '13.04.22',
    descriptionItems: 
    [
      { 
        title: 'BRIEF',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      },
      { 
        title: 'CONFLICTS',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    image: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/500?grayscale',
    title: 'AERO',
    category: 'development',
    date: '23.01.10',
    descriptionItems: 
    [
      { 
        title: 'BRIEF',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      },
      { 
        title: 'CONFLICTS',
        description: 'Duis suscipit interdum iaculis. Cras a sagittis tortor, in ultrices mi.'
      }
    ]
  },
]

var currentList = [];

var currentlySelectedItemId;

const listView = document.querySelector('#left');
const itemView = document.querySelector('#right');

function filterItems(arr, query) {
  
  let filteredItems;
  
  if (query) {
    
    let filteredItems = arr.filter(obj => {
      return obj.category === query;
    })
    
    return filteredItems;
    
  } else {
    return arr;
  }
  
}

function createList() {
  
  let listItems;
  const listContainer = document.querySelector('.list__container');
  
  // clear left container
  listContainer.innerHTML = '';
  
  // create list dom element 
  const itemList = document.createElement('ul');
  itemList.setAttribute('class', 'list');
  
  // create filter tabs 
  const filterTabsContainer = document.createElement('div');
  filterTabsContainer.setAttribute('class', 'filter__tabs');
  
  // create filter buttons
  const filterAllBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const filterDevBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const filterDesignBtn = document.createElement('button');
  
  filterAllBtn.setAttribute('class', 'filter-tab__item');
  filterDevBtn.setAttribute('class', 'filter-tab__item');
  filterDesignBtn.setAttribute('class', 'filter-tab__item');
  
  filterAllBtn.innerHTML = 'All';
  filterDevBtn.innerHTML = 'Dev';
  filterDesignBtn.innerHTML = 'Design';
  
  // event handlers
  filterAllBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    listItems = filterItems(projects);  // filter list items 
    addButtonsToList(listItems); // create buttons 
    currentList = listItems;
    
  });
  
  filterDevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    listItems = filterItems(projects, 'development');
    addButtonsToList(listItems);
    currentList = listItems;
    
  });
  
  filterDesignBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    listItems = filterItems(projects, 'design');
    addButtonsToList(listItems);
    currentList = listItems;
    
    
  });
  
  
  filterTabsContainer.appendChild(filterAllBtn);
  filterTabsContainer.appendChild(filterDevBtn);
  filterTabsContainer.appendChild(filterDesignBtn);
  
  listContainer.appendChild(filterTabsContainer);
  listContainer.appendChild(itemList);

  // add active class functionality
  const filterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-tab__item');
  filterBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      filterBtns.forEach(f => f.classList.remove('is-active'));
      e.target.classList.toggle("is-active");
    });
  });

  listItems = filterItems(projects);
  filterAllBtn.classList.add('is-active');

  currentList = listItems;
  
  // create list 
  addButtonsToList(listItems);
  
}

function createListButton(itemText, itemCategory) {
  
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute('class', 'list__item__button');
  
  let buttonInnerHtml =  `
    <span class="list__item--text">${itemText}</span>
    <span class="list__item--category">${itemCategory}</span>
  `;
  
  
  button.innerHTML = buttonInnerHtml;
  
  return button;
}

function addButtonsToList(listItems) {
  
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');

  list.innerHTML = '';
  
  // generate list buttons from list
  listItems.forEach((item, key) => {
    
    // create list item
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.setAttribute('class', 'list__item');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-id', '' + key);
      
    const listButtons = [];
    listButtons.push(createListButton(item.title, item.category));
    
    // add buttons to list-item
    listButtons.forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {   
        
        // get current item ID
        let itemId = button.parentElement.dataset.id;
        
        // set the current item 
        currentlySelectedItemId = itemId;
        setDescription(currentlySelectedItemId);    
        
        // if we are on mobile then scroll into view
        itemView.scrollIntoView();
      });
      
      listItem.appendChild(button);
    });
    // add buttons to list
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  })
}

function setDescription(indexOfItem) {
  // get project item array index
  let projectItem = currentList[indexOfItem];
  
  // get item content 
  const item = document.querySelector('.item__content');
  
  // check if item content exists
  if (item) { item.remove() }
  
  // create description
  createDescription(projectItem.title, projectItem.date, projectItem.category,  projectItem.image,projectItem.descriptionItems)
};

function createDescription(itemTitle, itemDate, itemCategory, itemImage, descItems) {
  
  // Create desc container DOM element
  const desc = document.createElement('div');
  desc.setAttribute('class', 'item__content');
  
  // create desc innerHTML
  let descContent = `
      <div class="item__header">
        <button id="item__back" class="item__back"></button>
        <span class="item__title">${itemTitle}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item__image"></div>
      <div class="item__detail__group">
        <span class="item__detail__date">${itemDate}</span>
        <span class="item__detail__category">${itemCategory}</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="item__description__list">
      </ul>
  `;
  
  
  // put desc content into container
  desc.innerHTML = descContent;

  // append item container to the RIGHT-side view
  itemView.appendChild(desc);
  
  // get description list container
  const descList = document.querySelector('.item__description__list');
  
  // create description list items
  descItems.forEach(item => {
    
    // create DOM element
    const descItem = document.createElement('li');
    descItem.setAttribute('class', 'description__item');
    
    // create desc item
    let descItemContent = `
      <span class="item__desc--title">${item.title}</span><span class="item__desc--text">${item.description}</span>
    `;
    
    // put desc item content into desc item container
    descItem.innerHTML = descItemContent;
    
    // append list item to desc
    descList.appendChild(descItem);
  })
  
  // set backbutton functionality
  const backBtn = document.querySelector('#item__back');
  backBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    listView.scrollIntoView();
  });
  
  // set item image
  const image = document.querySelector('.item__image');
  image.style.backgroundImage = `url(${itemImage}&?t=${Date.now()})`;
  
}

function createAbout() {
  const leftContainer = document.querySelector('.list__container');
  
  let aboutHtml = `
    <p class="about">
      Welcome to the list view component!</p>
  `;
  
  itemView.innerHTML = '';
  
  leftContainer.innerHTML = aboutHtml;
  
  
  
}

// add navigation tab functionality
function setTabButtons() {
  
  // add active class functionality
  const tabBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-nav]');
  tabBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      tabBtns.forEach(f => f.classList.remove('is-active'));
      e.target.classList.toggle("is-active");
    });
  });
  
  const workBtn = document.querySelector("[data-nav='work']");
  const aboutBtn = document.querySelector("[data-nav='about']");
  
  workBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createList();
  });
  
  aboutBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createAbout();
  });
}

(function initComponent() {
  createList();
  setTabButtons();  
})();
```

```css
// CSS 
/* global */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* container & wrapper */

.content__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* content box */

.content {
  
  border: 2px solid #000;
  
  display: flex;
  
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 80vh;
}

/* left & right wrapper */

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  width: 40%
}

.right {
  width: 60%
}

.left {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

/* about */

.about {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Consolas', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
}

/* list & list item */

/* list */

.list__container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;  
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  
  
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  direction: rtl;
  
}

/* scrollbar */

.about::-webkit-scrollbar,
.list::-webkit-scrollbar,
.item__description__list::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 10px;
}

.about::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.list::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.item__description__list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.about::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.item__description__list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 border-right: 0; 
 border-left: 2px solid black;
}

.about::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.item__description__list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

.about::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover,
.list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover, 
.item__description__list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

/* list item */

.list__item {
  width: 100%;
  
  list-style: none;
  
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  
  direction: ltr;
}

.list__item--text, .list__item--category {
  display: inline;
}

.list__item--category {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.list__item--text {
  min-width: 13vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.list__item--text:before {
  content: '◯';
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: 15%;
}

.list__item button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.list__item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.list__item:hover .list__item--text:before {
  content: '◉';
}

.list__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* item content */

.item__content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item__header {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.item__title {
  padding: 7px 10px;
}

.item__back {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: none;
}

.item__back:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item__back:before {
  content: '￩';
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.item__image {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15vh 70px;
  background-color: black;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  
}


.item__detail__group {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item__detail__date {
  
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.item__detail__category, .item__detail__date {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item__description__list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
}

.item__description::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.item__description::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.item__description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

.item__description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.description__item {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.item__desc--title, .item__desc--text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.description__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* tabs */

.nav__tabs {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  display:flex;
}

.filter__tabs {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.nav-tabs__item, .filter-tab__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.filter-tab__item {
  padding: 7px 10px;
}

.filter-tab__item {
  padding: 7px 5%;
}

.nav-tabs__item:hover,
.filter-tab__item:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.is-active:hover  {
  opacity: .8;
}

/* reset button styles */

button {
  border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;

    background: transparent;

    /* inherit font & color from ancestor */
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;

    /* Normalize `line-height`. Cannot be changed from `normal` in Firefox 4+. */
    line-height: normal;

    /* Corrects font smoothing for webkit */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;

    /* Corrects inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* media queries */


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
  .item__back {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .item__title {
    padding: 7px 0;
  }
  
  .content {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .left, .right {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .left {
    border: 0;
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
 // HTML
 <div class="content__wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="left" class="left">
      <div class="list__container">
      </div>
     <nav class="nav__tabs">
       <button data-nav="work"  id="nav__work" class="nav-tabs__item is-active">Work</button>
       <button data-nav="about" id="nav__about" class="nav-tabs__item">About</button>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="right"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For starter I would change `innerHTML` with `textContent` in JS. `innerHTML` poses a security risk (XSS-injections) and is "slow" because the DOM needs to be re-parsed.